# Use Pivot to convert rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I know this question has been asked before, and I did find answers but I am still having trouble implementing `PIVOT`.

Current table:

```
day      hour  sales_val
------------------------
Monday   8     110.12
Monday   9     51.58
Monday   10    78.98
Tuesday  9     207.38
Tuesday  10    61.30
...
```

Expected result:

```
hour  monday  tuesday    ...
----------------------------
8     110.12  NULL
9     51.58   207.38
10    78.98   61.30
```

The table will always contain 7 different days (Monday to Sunday) and will not always contain the same hours, hence the `NULL` value. As mentionned I found various answers implementing `PIVOT`, but I don't quite understand how to use it there.

Comment: use DATEPART ( dw, date_col ) for getting weekday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pivot query to output this would be:

```
SELECT [hour],  [Monday], [Tuesday]
FROM (
    SELECT [day], [hour], [sales_val] FROM YourTable
) AS src
PIVOT (
    SUM(sales_val) FOR [day] IN ([Monday], [Tuesday])
) AS pvt
```

And if you want to have zeros rather than nulls in your output, then just `COALESCE` the results:

```
SELECT [hour],  COALESCE([Monday], 0) AS [Monday], COALESCE([Tuesday], 0) AS [Tuesday]
FROM (
    SELECT [day], [hour], [sales_val] FROM YourTable
) AS src
PIVOT (
    SUM(sales_val) FOR [day] IN ([Monday], [Tuesday])
) AS pvt
```

*Obviously this only does Monday and Tuesday - expand as you need it...*

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Looks simple when reading it, but I couldn't write it myself. Thanks.